# android Finding the point FromScreenLocation on mapsV2

Tags: android, google-maps

Hi I am trying to use Projection on a map project.. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/Projection.html#fromScreenLocation%28android.graphics.Point%29/%22Here%22) it says that fromScreenLocation(Point point) method returns the geographic position .. So have can I determine my ImageView's point to find it's geographic position on maps? What can be the value of the point that referred in fromScreenLocation method?

Answer (score 0):

you can get the `getX()` and `getY()` to get the x and y position in pixels of your imageview on the screen. you will probably have to do additional math to then find the bottom middle of you image so that you will get the position that your imageview is pointing to on the map

see [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) for more details on what you can use to get the position in pixels

Comment: ImageView v=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.view);
  TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.test);
  right=v.getRight();
  tv.setText("fromRight"+right);  this returns 0..  any idea?